# Pandas: First column access of dataframe very slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have merged two large dataframes and am consecutively accessing pairs of columns (as in `df[[col1, col2]]`). First time, the retrieval is *very* slow while the following ones are as fast as "normal". Why is this and how can I avoid it?

Ex.

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate two big dataframes with common column values
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(800000, 3))
df2 = df1.sample(len(df1)).reset_index(drop=True)
# merge on column 0
df = df1.merge(df2, on=0)

# time retrieval of suffixed columns
start = time()
df[['1_x', '1_y']];
print('1st access:', time() - start)

start = time()
df[['2_x', '2_y']];
print('2nd access:', time() - start)
```

The output is

```
1st access: 2.8012924194335938
2nd access: 0.003415822982788086
```

Comment: Probably has to do with caching. I assume after the first access the data is in cache, and therefore faster to access.

Comment: @sagi A curious thing is that retrieving only _one_ column is "normal" speed both times (as in `df['1_x']` and `df['2_x']`). Why is that behaving differently and, more to your comment, what cache is being used?

Comment: That's actually very interesting! Lots of options of what could be causing it I'd say. Check data types, the size of the actual data in the different column (use .info(memory_usage='deep')), try accessing the first 2 column twice to test out @sagi's theory about cache

Comment: @rayad I agree! Retrieving the same two column twice gives similar times as retrieving another pair of columns (as done in the example).

Comment: If the other things i mentioned don't give some insight then I guess it's possible there's some sort of caching happening (but I didn't think pa das does that..). Another test would be make a bigger df (don't use the sample approach you took just copy the first df line), merge, then test on a bunch more columns